# Roblox LUA. Press a certain key near an object

Tags: lua, roblox

I am pretty new at scripting and what I want is when a player is near an object (let’s say a car spawner) the player can type a letter on there keyboard and a GUI will show up. And the other thing is the same thing but for tools. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ProximityPrompt.
Another way is a ton of complex(ish) code that uses `UserInputService` to detect input and some other code to detect key presses within a range.

ProximityPrompt does everything you need without any complexity, though.